# How do I plot the coordinates of a spatial dataset when plotting it over a shapefile in R?

Tags: r, shapefile

I am plotting a SpatialPointsDataFrame object of archaeological finds over a shapefile of the trench they were found in. So far I have managed to load and plot both sets of data together with:

```
coordinates(finds) <- ~x+y
trencharea <- readOGR(dsn="excpoly", layer="excpoly")
trencharea <- as.owin(trencharea)

plot(trencharea, main= "Trench & Finds")
plot(finds, add=TRUE, col = "blue", pch = 4)
```

However, I also want the x and y coordinates associated with the finds to be displayed on the x and y axes of my plot. How do I do this? I'm not looking for a solution that involves ggplot

Comment: Without the datasets you have used, it is very difficult to help you out. Can you provide your datasets?

Comment: Are you getting the plot out of this `plot(trencharea, main= "Trench & Finds")`?

Comment: @BappaDas yep, the plot is coming out of that. I couldn't get x/y coordinates to show on the axes when plotting that or when adding the finds information. 

I can't provide the datasets themselves, but the finds data is formatted as "x","y","type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, are you looking for the following

```
plot(trencharea, main= "Trench & Finds")
plot(finds, add=TRUE, col = "blue", pch = 4)
axis(1)
axis(2)
box(col = 'black')
```

Dummy plot
[image]